# Applying caulk over new caulk

Tags: bathroom

A few days ago I scraped out all of the old caulk around our bath, cleaned and dried the area then applied an anti-mould bathroom sealant (neutral silicone). I don't think I applied a thick enough layer. There are no gaps but if you look closely you can see a few cracks in the sealant. Would I be able to apply another layer over the top or do I need to scrape it out and start again?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, silicone doesn't stick to silicone. So unless you can somehow bridge the entire bead of original caulk, you're stuck with the hard work of taking it all out again.

Comment: Appreciate the answer. Will try to bead first. Worst comes to worst, I'll take it all out and start again.